# Why are my accented characters breaking in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, character-encoding

When I update my database with this command:

UPDATE myTable SET Name = 'Hermann Dönnhoff' WHERE ID = 123;

SQL Server actually puts 'Hermann Do¨nnhoff' in the field instead. Instead of faithfully inserting the o-umlaut (char(246)), I'm getting two characters ( char(111) + char (168) ).
This happens for all characters that have accent marks, not just umlauts. 
Has anybody seen this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `nchar`, `nvarchar`, or `ntext` datatypes for Unicode data.

The issue is that your code page does not directly support those characters.

Read up on collations for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214408%28SQL.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28SQL.80%29.aspx